# How do I put static text in a select element in html?

Tags: html

I currently have a select element as follows:

```
<select class="select" id="startYear" onChange={(event) => setStartYear(event.target.value)}>
```

Then I have a bunch of options elements as well. Each looking as follows:

```
<option value=2017 selected={2017 == startYear}>2017</option>
<option value=2018 selected={2018 == startYear}>2018</option>
//lots of different years continuing on
```

I'm hoping to make it so that there's a static text that says `"Start:"` and then the dropdown  is just all of the years (without the text). See the image below as an example. Anyone know where I can add the `"Start:"` text?

[image: Example Drop Down]

Comment: Why not just define your options to have the first element have that text, then just don't use it in the rest? You're asking for static text, so write it in there. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I want the year to change. Like it should be able to change from `Start: 2017` to `Start: 2018`. However, I want the dropdown to just be a list of `2017`, `2018`, `2019` etc.

Comment: Essentially, I want the selected element to have `Start:` in front of it, but only in the overarching select box, not in the dropdown list. I also edited the question, so hopefully it's a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would usually use a label for this kind of thing, where the label is to the left and the select box to the right.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 10px
}

select {
  border: none
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="start">Start: </label>
  <select id="start">
    <option>2017</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

There is still an arrow there which your example image doesn't show, however, I would argue that you want to have the arrow there to denote that it's a select box/drop down. Without it, there's no indication and it's not friendly UX.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this effect by surrounding the whole thing in a div, and adding the text and select there. With some css, it looks like a normal select prompt. You may have to fiddle with some of the variables to make it to your liking.

```css
.select{
        display: inline-block;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .select select {
        display: inline-block;
        border: none;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .select select:focus-visible{
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
    }

    .select p {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="select">
    <p>Start:</p>
    <select>
        <option>15432542</option>
        <option>54326</option>
        <option>654262</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Dont forget create a noticeable :focus styles for keyboard accessibility by adding something like this in your css : (doesn't work on all browsers like firefox). See https://caniuse.com/css-has

`.select:has(select:focus) {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}`

Comment: Also, you can replace your  `p` element by a label like @Cjmarkham did